# pytorch LSTM model not learning

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I created a simple LSTM model to predict Uniqlo closing price. The problem is, my model doesn't seem to learn anything. This is the link to my [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1U1WcalD64wFVBNfhlTlXAI-E0w-ISedV?usp=sharing)

This is my model creation class (I tried relu activation function before, get the same outcome):

```
class lstm(torch.nn.Module):
  def __init__(self,hidden_layers):
    super(lstm,self).__init__()
    self.hidden_layers = hidden_layers
    self.lstm = torch.nn.LSTM(input_size = 2,hidden_size = 100,num_layers = self.hidden_layers,batch_first=True)
    self.hidden1 = torch.nn.Linear(100,80)
    self.dropout1 = torch.nn.Dropout(0.1)
    self.hidden2 = torch.nn.Linear(80,60)
    self.dropout2 = torch.nn.Dropout(0.1)
    self.output = torch.nn.Linear(60,1)

  def forward(self,x):
    batch = len(x)
    h = torch.randn(self.hidden_layers,batch,100).requires_grad_().cuda()
    c = torch.randn(self.hidden_layers,batch,100).requires_grad_().cuda()

    x,(ho,co)= self.lstm(x.view(batch,10,2),(h.detach(),c.detach()))
    x = torch.reshape(x[:,-1,:],(batch,-1))
    x = self.hidden1(x)
    x = torch.nn.functional.tanh(x)
    x = self.dropout1(x)
    x = self.hidden2(x)
    x = torch.nn.functional.tanh(x)
    x = self.dropout2(x)
    x = self.output(x)
    return x

model = lstm(10)
```

This is my training loss plot:
[training loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wilZi.png)

This is my validation loss plot:
[validation loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJHYb.png)

This is my ground truth (blue) vs prediction (orange):
[ground truth vs prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TvbF.png)

Can anyone please point out what did I do wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You train scaler with whole data. This is not a good strategy. You should use only the training data.

You don't have to scale targets. Use it directly or apply log function or use returns.

About hidden state and cell memory, why do you kept track gradients and detach them just after? You don't have to detach hidden state and cell memory when feeding lstm layer because it participates of back propagation.

If I understand what you did, you predict the next close price using the last 10 open prices and volumes. I don't think you can get good results with this configuration. You should formalize the problem better.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I am trying to predict the next value using the previous 10 values. I tried your suggestions, it still remain the same. To answer your question, I use "detach" to achieve truncated backpropagation through time (I saw this in a Kaggle notebook). It doesn't change the outcome even if I remove the detach and scale according to your suggestions. Do you spot any problems in my model? The model seems okay to me

Comment: As for the configuration, I tried using "open", "high", "low" to predict the "close" price before, it still the same. I keep getting the same value as output no matter what I feed in to the model during inference.

Comment: I don't think there is any causality between open, high, low and close price. By causality I mean any hidden structure that drives close price based on features. Use these features will most of the time gives you an output that represent either a sort of moving average or just a shifted close price; because there are correlated (features and target). Another thing you have to consider is that in practice you get OHLC prices together. So you use the four as features for the 10 previous values and predict the next close values.

Comment: Also, try different history length (10, 20, 30,  60, etc.) may be you can acheive better results.

Comment: About your model,may be it cannot learn anything well because you have lots hidden units just for 2 inputs.Try something simple like lstm(8) -> fc(8) -> fc(1).